# How do i get country ISO-Codes using PTV Geocoding API?

Tags: ptv-developer

I'm  integrating PTV Geocoding Api in ouer software. In ouer software countries are saved in Database with postal code format VAT and some other data.So i need some standartised Identifeier to save Address. We used countries ISO Codes for countries Identification.  Problem is PTV respondes with full country name in addresse. Is there any posibility to receive ISO Codes instead of full Country Names? Or I have to To make dictionary between names used in GeoCoding Api and ISO Codes?

Answer (score 0):

The current API implementation doe not return any ISO based country code. In fact you would have to define a dictionary and then enrich the outpout of the search with the ISO code manually:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictCountries = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictCountries.Add("United Kingdom", "GB");
dictCountries.Add("Germany", "DE");
dictCountries.Add("France", "FR");
```

and so on.